# Unable to check for already existing usernames google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, registration, google-cloud-datastore, user-registration

Here is my code to check for already existing usernames :

```
def post(self):
        have_error = False
        username = self.request.get('username')
        password = self.request.get('password')
        verify = self.request.get('verify')
        email = self.request.get('email')

        params = dict(username= username,
        email = email)

        usernames = db.GqlQuery(' select *  from Users where username = :1 ', username)


        if not valid_username(username):
            params['username_error'] = "Invalid username"
            have_error = True

        if usernames :
            params['username_error'] = 'Username already exists'
            have_error = True
```

With this code my form displays `Username already exists` for every username.

When the `params['username_error'] = 'Username already exists'` is changed to 
`params['username_error'] = usernames` ,

the message displayed in the `username_error` field is :

`<google.appengine.ext.db.GqlQuery object at 0x10a4e030>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd change your check to:

```
query = db.GqlQuery(' select *  from Users where username = :1 ', username)
usernames = query.count(limit=2)
```

Now, the `if usernames:` guard will have the effect you desire.

The reason is simple: in your code, you build a query object, which you call `usernames`, but you never actually **run** that query -- you check the object for truthiness, which happens to hold (as does for almost all Python objects except empty containers and strings, None, zero numbers) but signifies nothing.

Here, I run the query in the simplest way -- just count how many items it would return (just-counting is a bit faster than actually fetching them:-) and with a very low limit (since we only care about counts of 0, which is correct, and 1, which means a duplicate).

Now `usernames` is a number counting how many other times that user name appears in the datastore (with 1 standing for "once or more":-) and the rest of your logic becomes accurate.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex! I found a solution too though... I added a line after my `usernames` object creation - `user = usernames.get()` and changed the `if` to `if user:` . Having read your explanation I believe there something similar at work with the `.get()` method.

Comment: @VineetKaushik, yep, pretty much, the one reason I preferred `count` over `get` was to minimize the amount of data transferred in case a `User` has many or large properties, and there are many other ways to do that, too, such as keys-only queries.  And if the `User` entity has just a few small properties it doesn't really cost anything material to get it all anyway, it's just a habit one gets into, to only get on each datastore interaction as little as is really needed:-).